# Copying columns of data without skipping columns from one workbook to a compiling workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am importing data from several different databases and combining them into a simple report, however all of the databases have different layouts for example 1 database has the name in column 1 and the second has the name in column 2

i found some good examples in the forums however tying them into the importer has not been producing the correct results.

This code calls all the columns i need in the correct order however it places them all in 1 column

```
Sub importoer()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range
Dim v As Long, vcols As Variant

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [oer!A1]
vcols = Array(1, 2, 11, 4, 6, 7, 10, 3) 'columns to copy in this order

Sheets("oer").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose OER File", _
FileFilter:="All Files (*.*),*.*")

If FileToOpen = False Then
MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Exit Sub
Else

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
    With Sheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    For v = LBound(vcols) To UBound(vcols)
        .Columns(vcols(v)).Copy
        PasteStart.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
    Next v
    '.Copy

End With
Next Sheet
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

so i adding a column selection on the target page by changing the pastestart definition

```
Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Cells(1, v + 1)
```

This called all the columns except the 1st one and placed them  on the OER sheet with empty columns between each one.

Column 1 not copied
column 2 placed in column 1
column 11 placed in column 2
column 4 placed in column 4
column 6 placed in column 7 so -on

I need to figure out how to get them all place in columns 1 thru 8 in the call order

Any Thoughts?

>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? You were offsetting by rows, not columns

```
Sub importoer()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range
Dim v As Long, vcols As Variant

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = wb1.Sheets("oer").Range("A1")
vcols = Array(1, 2, 11, 4, 6, 7, 10, 3) 'columns to copy in this order

wb1.Sheets("oer").UsedRange.Cells.ClearContents
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose OER File", _
            FileFilter:="All Files (*.*),*.*")
If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
    For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        With Sheet
            For v = LBound(vcols) To UBound(vcols)
                .Columns(vcols(v)).Copy
                PasteStart.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(, 1)
            Next v
        End With
    Next Sheet
End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: That solved not calling the first column but still left the spacing between the rest.

Comment: never mind my last comment it worked i didn't remove the v +1 Thank you